# Push view controller on left swipe

Tags: ios, pushviewcontroller

How do i push view controller on swiping left(panning left) using panGesture?
Currently using SwipeRightToPopController `github` library to achieve pop view controller on panning right.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but this appears to do what you want: https://github.com/robertmryan/ScreenEdgeGestureNavigationController

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

In Viewdidload

```
 let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(handleSwipes) )
 let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(handleSwipes) )

 leftSwipe.direction = .left
 rightSwipe.direction = .right

 view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
 view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.direction == .left)
    {
        let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as UIViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(initialViewControlleripad, animated: false)
    }if(sender.direction == .right){

       let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as UIViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(initialViewControlleripad, animated: false)
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, But this won't go with the finger , I want a pan gesture type of feel while pushing the view controller 
eg: when you swipe from extreme left to right view gets popout

Comment: @MridulGupta I encountered the same problem to solve, did you find any solution to this?

Comment: ohh yes, it was long back, Now I can help you solve this @Guala. I will post the solution on this ticket

Comment: Thanks, where can find the solution? @MridulGupta

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**In ViewDidLoad :**

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftGesture=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftGesture];
swipeLeftGesture.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;// change direction as per your needs
```

**Its selector method:**

```
-(void)handleSwipeGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    NSUInteger touches = sender.numberOfTouches;
    if (touches == 2)
    {
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        { 
            //push view controller here    
        }
    }  
}
```

**Using Pan Gesture**

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

- (void)panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer
{
    CGPoint velocity = [panRecognizer velocityInView:self.view];

    NSLog(@"Pan Detected.");

    if (velocity.x > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Pan went right.");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Pan went left.");     

        if (panRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
            NSLog(@"push here ");

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Settings" sender:panRecognizer];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, But this won't go with the finger , I want a pan gesture type of feel while pushing the view controller 
eg: when you swipe from extreme left to right view gets popout